# Text appears on result on running java GUI code

Tags: java, user-interface, applet, awt, appletviewer

I am a beginner with advanced java. I have written a code of calculator in java:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
/*<applet code="calculator" width="300" height="279"></applet>*/
public class calculator extends Applet
{
    TextField t1;
    Button num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,num7,num8,num9,num0,dot,eq,ce,divide,multi,sub,addi;
    public void start()
    {
        t1=new TextField();
        num1=new Button("1");
        num2=new Button("2");
        num3=new Button("3");
        num4=new Button("4");
        num5=new Button("5");
        num6=new Button("6");
        num7=new Button("7");
        num8=new Button("8");
        num9=new Button("9");
        num0=new Button("0");   
        dot=new Button(".");
        eq=new Button("=");
        ce=new Button("CE");
        divide=new Button("/");
        multi=new Button("x");
        sub=new Button("-");
        addi=new Button("+");
        setLayout(null);
        t1.setBounds(2,2,296,30);
        num7.setBounds(2,34,74,49);
        num8.setBounds(76,34,74,49);
        num9.setBounds(150,34,74,49);
        num4.setBounds(2,83,74,49);
        num5.setBounds(76,83,74,49);
        num6.setBounds(150,83,74,49);
        num1.setBounds(2,132,74,49);
        num2.setBounds(76,132,74,49);
        num3.setBounds(150,132,74,49);
        num0.setBounds(76,181,74,49);
        dot.setBounds(2,181,74,49);
        eq.setBounds(150,181,74,49);
        divide.setBounds(224,34,74,49);
        multi.setBounds(224,83,74,49);
        sub.setBounds(224,132,74,49);
        addi.setBounds(224,181,74,49);
        ce.setBounds(2,230,296,49);
        add(t1);
        add(num1);
        add(num2);
        add(num3);
        add(num4);
        add(num5);
        add(num6);
        add(num7);
        add(num8);
        add(num9);
        add(num0);
        add(dot);
        add(eq);
        add(ce);
        add(divide);
        add(multi);
        add(sub);
        add(addi);
    }
}
```

When I compile this code with `javac calculator.java` and run this with `appletviewer calculator` the result is this:

[image]

Some unusual text like Applet(at the top) and Applet started(at the bottom) appears on the result. How can remove these text from the result? What changes I have to do to remove them? Why these texts appear on the result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try hiding the status bar which will fix your issue

Comment: 1) *"Some unusual text like Applet(at the top) and Applet started(at the bottom) appears on the result."* Those lines are part of the applet viewer.  *"How can remove these text from the result?"* They don't appear in a web page. Oh wait.. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web). 2) *"advanced java"* AWT was replaced by Swing around .. 16 years ago? Swing by Java-FX more recently.